# JavaScript error on page is preventing my jQuery handler from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using jQuery to add functionality to an existing page, whose markup and script I have no control over.  It works fine, until some other script on the page causes an error, which prevents my jQuery event handlers from executing.  Is there some way to have my jQuery code execute even after the page has errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a global error handling function to deal with the errors, which then would allow the rest of the code to execute properly.. Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    window.onerror = function (msg, url, num) {
        //do something if you need to.
        return true;
    }
});

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you create a demo which shows how an error is handled in practice? (I can't get it to work)

Comment: I don't get it. What difference does the `window.onerror` function make? It works the same if we just leave it out: http://www.jsfiddle.net/unRT7/1/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible unfortunately.